# Nlog not logging to SQL server

Tags: sql, .net, nlog

I've gone through the setup process to use Nlog in my .NET 6 web api app. Nlog is not logging to my database but I can't see where I've gone wrong.

This is my Nlog.config file:

[image]

This is the relevant part of my program.cs file:

[image]

My appsettings file:

[image]

And the controller where I am calling the logger:

[image]

A log should be added to the Logs table in my database but it isn't:

[image]

I have checked that the end point is being hit correctly and it is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Comment: Check the NLog InternalLogger output for errors. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging (Maybe missing NLog extension nuget-package [NLog.Database](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Database)).

Comment: Thanks for the responses and apologies for the late reply. The error output shows lots of errors relating to the debug targets: "Debug Targets not configured for Logger: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation"

Comment: Also, I've tried adding the package mentioned above but still the logs aren't being added to the database

Comment: `Debug Targets not configured for Logger` is not an error-message, but a Debug-notification. Maybe change `internalLogLevel=` from `Trace` to `Info` if you are getting lost in the internal-output. Another good idea is to enable `throwConfigExceptions="True"`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks Rolf and sorry again for late reply! Amending the internalLogLevel and the throwConfigExceptions has given me enough info to resolve the issue now. It seems the connectionString in my Nlog.config file needed changing.

Comment: Maybe update your answer with "1. how did you diagnose the issue?" and "2. what error-text lead you to the solution?"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Data Source attribute in the XML connection string seems to have resolved the issue:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
```